# MS Access: Continuous Forms and Subforms

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

Is there a more ideal way to create a form that gets sources from 2 different queries than getting a `mainform` and putting a `subform` inside?

Is there any way to make a `dynamic subform` that can expand depending on the number of entries it outputs?

My gripe with using a Continuous form is that it also shows the blank "`next`" entry.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1) It is not possible to say, what is "ideal way". Solution depends on your actual requirements. E.g. I sometimes use "list" of values from second query on place of subform from that second query.

Another way is to turn your viewpoint upside down and try "hang" your form on your second query (or on some table from that second query) and "stick" needed data to the form according to your requirements (e.g. by subform, by calculated field, by dlookup, by vbscript subroutine, or whatever you need)

2) Regard "new entry" - try test all options about "can insert new", "can edit", "read only" etc.